# Messed up Desktop and animations by installing script from GitHub (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, github, animations, latte-dock

So I tried to use some [script](https://github.com/alex47/KDE-Rounded-Corners) from GitHub to get rounded window corners, after running it tho, instead of removing the corners, most animations and transitions seem to be disabled aswell as other stuff not responding.

So my question is, is there a way to reverse the process/delete the stuff that causes all that?

If it helps, I'm on the LTS 20.04 with a Latte-dock/panel on an old ass ThinkPad T410 running only Kubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

`cd`  to the build directory and try `sudo make uninstall`. Many well-behaved `makefile`s have an `uninstall` target.

OR

Install the `checkinstall` package, and redo your `make install` under control of `installwatch`.

OR

Restore from backup. You should have backups.